# How to Hide the add to cart button on all product pages in magento frontend

Tags: magento, button, addition, store, cart

I am looking to hide the button "add to cart" on the product pages within the magento store. My products just hold information. You cannot purchase them.

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out the code that calls the button in the view.phtml file in the following location.

```
 app/design/frontend/default/your theme/template/catalog/product/
```

If you search for 'button' you should find the section of code pretty quickly.

This will remove it from the product page. If you need to remove it from the catalog list page, do the same thing in list.phtml (don't forget both list and grid versions)